# Post request header: need fingerprint and re_token to pass it

Tags: javascript, python, php, fingerprint

So im trying to login to anghami.com using post request. I was able to login if I pass all of the values needed.
My issue is im not sure were to find the 2 missing values "re_token" ( I guess its recapthca from google) and "fingerprint"

check my code for working test:

```
headers = {
        'authority': '',
        'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        'origin': 'https://play.anghami.com',
        'referer': 'https://play.anghami.com/login',
        'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
        'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
        'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
        }
link = 'https://api.anghami.com/gateway.php'
s = requests.Session()
proxies = {
  "http": "http://",
}
data = {
            'm': 'an',
            'u': 'email',
            'p': 'password',
            'devicename': 'Chrome 104',
            're_token':'03ANYolqvEDNfBhyM-qJ77j92_vkw8yt1VtKKc9e6jZFl9mG4sysFOvVZ0LlQWsMecFRWRCMFGG8KAgdWw1S0kUPB-1yW5kfJ8B2XGLnlaW7XAReGvyYpB2WgZeGXPdxlTi0PINbN2Ga9wI2ecF9jltpf7gcUj9MLucb9KDaUYENySmFq2ts5qh9g_2nr6AXx_igsD53xvWPGrGi_n7evy224P7A0NitmjcXKlAKL_rlkkXqbwOd4qbzF_IkTKX6iSNLfb2FFso8S75OKa0dlbfLO_7eY2zU7VzVKa23XWet3RXDED7q8Rx8RKFaO9n_lvbG-PORGCpmajnbWtWoIhEZpY06mt41vx4AoW0JnCtV9Z3v5AsAoM_SIZNawTLVBKyI3iVk9AbsGskh5DZ0DzIQ2Hp_2325fuyhjp2gjW_yUud7DuGVZ9Zn7WjteVnE0Yv4ZQoWx5Z2Hz-s7Qy7G2Acm6WLbuIvS_5JsJsfLYh_hiB_DY79UyKHNpeQtulqS1wMGwHqDFbmfv',
            'ngsw-bypass': 'true',
            'type': 'authenticate',
            'language': 'en',
            'lang': 'en',
            'web2': 'true',
            'fingerprint': 'eyJmcCI6ImE2MzcxYTRjLTU1ODEtNDE2My1iMWRkLTA3NjBkMmI5OWZlYSIsImgiOiI0OTIxZDM1OCJ9',
            'angh_type': 'authenticate',
        }

auth = HTTPProxyAuth(proxyacc)
s.proxies = proxies
s.auth = auth
ext_ip = s.post(link, data=data, headers=headers)
print (ext_ip.text)
print (ext_ip.url)
```

How can I create `'fingerprint':`
how to get `'re_token':`

Answer (score 1):

So,

1. re_token -> recaptcha token(answer)
2. fingerprint -> base64  encoded string with fingerprint uid and
   unknown 'h' param.

For more accurate information needed debug `vendor.67cc4b67b66a6114.js` this code.

As for the recaptcha, you need to understand what type of captcha is used on the site and, accordingly, find the key and additional information if needed.

To solve it, you can use any ready-made service like anti-captcha.

By the way, it's a bad idea to specify the `authority` header, since this header is specified automatically and works only with http2.0, otherwise, it betrays you even more.

Comment: Okay so re_token is what it is its easy
Can you help me with what you suggested for the fingerprint ?

Comment: Unfortunately, it takes a lot of time to resolve this issue. With such a question, you need to contact freelance.

As I said, you need to debug the ```vendor.67cc4b67b66a6114.js``` script and see how and what is generated.

Comment: okay thanks I tried to response = requests.get('https://anghamiwebcdn.akamaized.net/web/vendor.67cc4b67b66a6114.js', headers=headers)
I got tons of content

Comment: You need to use browser debugging to understand how and what is being generated.

You can read about it here:

https://nira.com/chrome-developer-tools/
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/

Comment: I will definitely study that! Thanks for sharing. can I hire you by any chance ?

Comment: Not at all, by the way, here is an interesting part of the code, in the future, you can study it.

https://ie.wampi.ru/2022/08/05/image.png

As for hiring, yes you can, but we need to discuss all the technical requirements.
Where can we do it?

Comment: yes I saw that. ok sounds good. HMU on Telegram @Jaypixx